# Am I doing my JOINS incorrectly, Output not as expected?

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to get a desired output as shown below however I am not sure why I am not getting it correctly. I don't know why I am getting movies such as "Date Night" or "Drive Angry" show up as they have no `MovieID` inside of tblReview. I thought I would have `Critic` and `User` on every line however for some reason I only have it on two lines for my output. My average's are also incorrect, however some of them use scientific notation.

In what ways can I fix these issues described above?

Script:

```
SELECT MovieTitle AS "MOVIE", TBLCRITICCLASS.CRITICCLASSDESC AS "Critic Type", AVG(TBLREVIEW.REVIEWSTAR) AS "Average Rating"
FROM TBLMOVIE
FULL JOIN TBLREVIEW ON TBLMOVIE.MOVIEID = TBLREVIEW.MOVIEID
FULL JOIN TBLCRITIC ON TBLREVIEW.CRITICID = TBLCRITIC.CRITICID
FULL JOIN TBLCRITICCLASS ON TBLCRITIC.CRITICID = TBLCRITICCLASS.CRITICCLASSID 
group by MovieTitle, TBLCRITICCLASS.CRITICCLASSDESC
Order by Movietitle;
```

Output with script:

```
MOVIE                               Critic Type                                        Average Rating
----------------------------------- ------------------------- ---------------------------------------
30 Minutes or Less                                                                            3.8E+00
A Lonely Place to Die               Critic                                                          9
A Lonely Place to Die                                                                         8.7E+00
Abraham Lincoln: Vampire Hunter                                                                      
Act of Valor                                                                                         
Captain America: The First Avenger                                                                   
Date Night                                                                                           
Drive Angry                                                                                          
Saving Private Ryan                                                                                  
Taken                               User                                                            6
Taken                                                                                          6.9375
Taken 2                                                                                           5.6


13 rows selected
```

Expected output:

```
MOVIE                           Critic Type  Average Rating
------------------------        ------------ --------------
30 Minutes or Less              Critic                 2.00
30 Minutes or Less              User                   4.20
A Lonely Place to Die           Critic                10.00
A Lonely Place to Die           User                   8.50
Taken                           Critic                 6.17
Taken                           User                   7.27
Taken 2                         Critic                 4.00
Taken 2                         User                   6.29

8 rows selected
```

Here are the files associated:

[File1 (Pastebin)](http://pastebin.com/yCmYPtAC)

[File 2 (Pastebin)](http://pastebin.com/etWUTC63)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start with `INNER JOIN`:

```
SELECT MovieTitle AS "MOVIE", TBLCRITICCLASS.CRITICCLASSDESC AS "Critic Type", AVG(TBLREVIEW.REVIEWSTAR) AS "Average Rating"
FROM TBLMOVIE INNER JOIN
     TBLREVIEW
     ON TBLMOVIE.MOVIEID = TBLREVIEW.MOVIEID INNER JOIN
     TBLCRITIC
     ON TBLREVIEW.CRITICID = TBLCRITIC.CRITICID INNER JOIN
     TBLCRITICCLASS
     ON TBLCRITIC.CRITICID = TBLCRITICCLASS.CRITICCLASSID 
group by MovieTitle, TBLCRITICCLASS.CRITICCLASSDESC
Order by Movietitle;
```

Your database should have proper foreign key relationships and you seem to want rows that match in the different tables.

If this doesn't work, then check the `JOIN` conditions.  For instance, this doesn't look right:  `TBLCRITIC.CRITICID = TBLCRITICCLASS.CRITICCLASSID`.  However, you don't describe the tables, so it is not possible to determine what the right conditions are.

Comment: I only get two lines for the output aside from the column names, I tried this before, however I didn't get my correct output

Comment: I added the tables into the post.

Comment: @AsadMahmood Gordon has it. tblCritic was being joined to tblCriticClass  on the wrong column.  It should be `ON TBLCRITIC.CRITICCLASSID = TBLCRITICCLASS.CRITICCLASSID`

Comment: @Gordon Linoff, Foreign key for table is must or not? Is there any performance improvement we will will get?

Comment: @RGS . . . An explicit foreign key reference generally has no performance implications  It helps the database maintain relational integrity.